CloudFront Key Value Store operations fail with `resolve_auth_scheme': No supported auth scheme for this endpoint
When attempting to access the CloudFront function APIs, such as DescribeKeyValueStore, I get an error saying that there is no supported auth scheme for this endpoint. The region of the client is set, and other AWS APIs work. However, this API does not. How do I resolve this error?
/Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.201.1/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoints.rb:32:in `resolve_auth_scheme': No supported auth scheme for this endpoint. (RuntimeError)
        from /Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-cloudfrontkeyvaluestore-1.10.0/lib/aws-sdk-cloudfrontkeyvaluestore/plugins/endpoints.rb:41:in `call'
        from /Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.201.1/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/endpoint_discovery.rb:84:in `call'
        from /Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.201.1/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/endpoint.rb:46:in `call'
        from /Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.201.1/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:26:in `call'
        from /Users/kjw/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.201.1/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:16:in `call'


It turns out that CloudFront Key Value Store uses a different signing algorithm than the usual sigv4: sigv4a. This is not supported by default. Support can be added with the aws-crt gem. I added this to my Gemfile, and the API calls started working:
gem 'aws-crt' '~> 0.2'
